# javascript code to make a div slide down and up (show/hide)

Tags: javascript

I have a page and I have little question mark images next to sections where if the question mark image is clicked, a div right below the section will appear sliding the rest of the page down.  Essentially a slide down/slide up javascript function.

Ex:

```
Section Title (? IMG)
<div id="section">blah blah blah</div>
<br><br>
Section Title 2 (? IMG)
<div id="section2">Blah2 blah2 blah2</div>
```

In my example above, the content inside div section and div section2 is hidden at first, but when the ? IMG is clicked for that section, the content will reveal itself and the rest of the page will slide down at the same time to make room for the content inside the divs.  And on reverse, if the question mark image is clicked while content is shown, it will slide up and hide itself and the page below will slide up as well filling the gap.

How would I write this?  I need it expandable so I can add multiple div's which can be titled accordingly and expanded individually.

Thanks

Comment: that does not help. I've obviously looked around for this but can't find a working script.  This is why I asked in javascript section.  I know its going to be javascript/jquery related.  The problem is I don't write javascript, so was needing someones help creating it or finding it.

Comment: Seems you didn't look at jQuery :). I added an example for you.

Comment: I appreciate it.  That sorta works, but it doesnt address my needing multiple of these to work individually on the same page.  I added this comment to your answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for instance:-

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="btn">section Title (? IMG)</div>
<div class="section">blah blah blah</div>
</div>

    <div class="wrapper">
<div class="btn">section Title (? IMG)</div>
<div class="section">Blah2 blah2 blah2</div>
        </div>

<script>
$(function(){
      $('.btn').click(function(e){
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('slideOut');
        });
});
</script>



.section{
    display:none;
}
.slideOut .section{
display:block;
}
.btn
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: works perfect.  Is there a minor adjustment for this to make it slide up and slide down compared to just appearing?  Or is that a big difference in code?

Comment: It is just a minor adjustment, just use slide toggle as shown below   :$('.btn').click(function(e){
        $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
    });

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can do this:

HTML:

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123" />
```

Script:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').slideDown('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Source: jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

To include jQuery on a HTML page, you can use the following in the head:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You could also download it yourself at place it on the server you want.

EDIT: Full answer with ready code then....

HTML:

```
<h1 id="id1" class="clickme">click1</h1>
<div id="section1">blah blah blah</div>
<br><br>
<h1 id="id2" class="clickme">click2</h1>
<div id="section2">Blah2 blah2 blah2</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });   
});
```

Comment: How would I make this work as if the image is hidden and they click click me, it will expand.  If it is already expanded and they click click me, it will hide.  Also, I need this to work with multiple divs within the same script (so I would need clickme, clickme1, clickme2...would I just copy the clickme.click function and saname it multiple times for each?

Comment: That's a lot of questions. I think you need to spend a little bit of time with some tutorials. Check this out for starters: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hk5oXFtYLwE